# jquery add html element to table

Tags: jquery, html, addition

I want to add a link to an empty html table. It works on Firefox and Chrome within 0.2 secs but not in IE9. There it takes at least 3 minutes. The reason is that the data delivered is completely different. I made the same queries in all three browsers. Here is my code:

```
function submitForm(dataString) 
{

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'text',
        url: 'retrieveFileList.php',
        data: {'data':dataString},
        success: function(data){
            jQuery('#tresults').append(data);
        }
    });

    return false;
}
```

The returned data from the php-file looks like this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{

$linktextpos = strrpos($row[0],"/",0);
$linktext = substr($row[0],$linktextpos);

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>";
echo "</td>";
echo "<td>";
echo "<a color='#ffffff' href=\"" . $row[0] . "\"><font color=\"#ffffff\">" . "..." . $linktext . "</font></a>";
echo "</td>";
echo "</tr>";

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Found the problem. I had the wrong header for my HTML-file.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
```

MSIE browsers do not recognise this (no PublicID) and render it in Quirks mode and therefore document.getElementById()... was not working and sql got handed the wrong parameters. Puuh.

It should say:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/HTML4/loose.dtd">
```

Answer (score 0):

How many rows does your php return? I haven't tested this, but I guess IE9 might be less smart about inserting a large number of rows into a table. Try inserting it like this:

```
jQuery('#tresults').append($(data));
```

If that doesn't help, try wrapping your php output in `<tbody></tbody>`.

.

Comment: I tried both but the data which is returned in IE9 is different. For example i have ten specific rows in FF and Chrome and 100 other rows in IE9. The sql-queries are the same. I really don't understand this.

Comment: Unless your server-side code is specifically checking for user agent and returning different output depending on it, there is no way one browser can get different results than others. Check if your dataString is the same in IE9. It can fail if you are encoding special characters.

Comment: I don't check for user agent on the server. The returned data is different for IE9. I know it shouldn't but it is. The links are not the same. I get different links. Strange.

Comment: Ok. I used fiddler to check the web-traffic and found out that for some reason Javascript is not working properly on IE9 and the result is that default-values and not selected parameters are submitted to SQL which leads to wrong results transmitted back. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: That's what I meant when I told you to check your dataString. Your dataString is the serialized data that is being submitted to the server. Insert it somewhere into the document or alert it, then compare the output in FF or Chrome with IE9 output. It should tell you what IE9 is doing wrong.